# Configure Fluent-bit file output plugin set file rollover

Tags: fluent-bit

I've a Fluent-bit running as docker instance which uses `tail` input plugin to read  docker log files and currently I've configured output plugin to use Elasticsearch.

However in prod since Elasticsearch resides on another zone, don't want to consume bandwidth I don't want to use Elasticsearch, instead want to use `file` output plugin. But in [file plugin](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/output/file) there is no documentation explaining the file rollover configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no such feature in Fluent Bit File output plugin. Please log the enhancement request on GitHub:

https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/new?template=feature_request.md

Since this feature makes a lot of sense it can be implemented shortly,

regards,

Eduardo
Fluent Bit Maintainer